# Pyspark join conditions using dictionary values for keys

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm working on a script that tests the contents of some newly generated tables against production tables. The newly generated tables may or may not have the same column names and may have multiple columns that have to be used in join conditions. I'm attempting to write out a function with the needed keys being passed using a dictionary.
something like this:

```
def check_subset_rel(self, remote_df, local_df, keys):
    join_conditions = []
    for key in keys:
        join_conditions.append(local_df.key['local_key']==remote_df.key['remote_key'])

    missing_subset_df = local_df.join(remote_df, join_conditions, 'leftanti')
```

pyspark/python doesn't like the dictionary usage in `local_df.key['local_key']` and `remote_df.key['remote_key']`. I get a "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'key'" error. I'm pretty sure that it's expecting the actual name of the column instead of any variable, but I'm not sure if I can make that conversation between value and column name.

Does anyone know how I could go about this?

Comment: try `local_df[key['local_key']] == remote_df[key['remote_key']]`?

Comment: Wow! Thank you! That worked like a champ! Thank you very, very much! How do I give you credit for your answer?